# How to share my own website on facebook with image from website

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-like, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

I added share and like button on my website.

```
http://5.135.145.154/product?id=1
```

But I have got problem, I can share the website but how can I set my own image on this share frame? I have one main image of product and I want to share this image and description, but on facebook there is different image (I think random image from website?)

This code shares my image:

```
<script>
(function(d, s, id) {
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/cs_CZ/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=59782362627&version=v2.0";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://5.135.145.154/product?id=${product.id }" data-layout="button" data-action="like" data-show-faces="false" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have Open Graph Metatags (especially `og:image` )defined in your html?
From the [Facebook Sharing Best Practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#tags) about the `og-image`-tag:

> The URL of the image that will appear when someone shares the content to Facebook. Please see our best practices guide to learn how to specify a high quality preview image and our documentation on images to specify width and height.

If you don't have that set, the Facebook Crawler will just use a random image, like in your current case.

Comment: Hi, I tried it `http://5.135.145.154/product?id=11` if you can see I added meta tags into head but it doesn't help